# Fetched Core Database Data into Array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I'm new IOS developer and I'm working with Core database. I have a table with 3 different attributes (String, Date, Double). I want to fetch the 3 attributes into a separate array. So I can display them in table view perfectly. 
I am using Xcode 8 and swift 3.

I tried to put them in array as shown bellow but I got this **error**:

> Thread1 :Error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. Also, in the output window shows 
>   fatal error: Index out of range

```
var first = [String]()
var last = [Double]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let request = NSFetchRequest <NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName : "EXPENSEAMOUNT_TABLE")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let result = try self.context.fetch(request)

        if (result.count > 0) {
            for index in 0 ..< result.count
            {
                let person = result[index] as! NSManagedObject

                 last [index] = person.value(forKey : "expenseAmount") as! Double //ERROR fires here
                first [index] = person.value(forKey: "expenseAccountCode") as! String
                  //  let second = person.value(forKey: "expenseDate") // I hide this because I don't know how to save the date into an array ?

            }
        }

    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)
    }

    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customeCell
    cell.dateText.text = first[indexPath.row]
    cell.amountText.text = String (last[indexPath.row])


    return cell
}
```

how can I fix this  !!

Comment: Where are you adding data to the `first` and `last` arrays?

Comment: last [index] = person.value(forKey : "expenseAmount") as! Double here. I changed the way of fetching the data please go check my answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

The way you are implementing tableview is wrong. You should return the number of rows from number of rows in section.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let request = NSFetchRequest <NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName : "EXPENSEAMOUNT_TABLE")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let result = try self.context.fetch(request)

        if (result.count > 0) {
            for index in 0 ..< result.count
            {
                let person = result[index] as! NSManagedObject

                last [index] = person.value(forKey : "expenseAmount") as! Double //ERROR fires here
            first [index] = person.value(forKey: "expenseAccountCode") as! String


            }
        }

    } catch {
         let fetchError = error as NSError
         print(fetchError)
    }
return result.count
}
```

Then return the cell from cell for row at index path

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:   "cell", for: indexPath) as! customeCell
    cell.dateText.text = first[indexPath.row]
    cell.amountText.text = String (last[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I got the same problem " Thread1 :Error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION "

Answer (score 0):

I tried other way to display the data into tableView as shown bellow. 
the problem now it will print for me the last record each time in the raw table

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let request = NSFetchRequest <NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName : "EXPENSEAMOUNT_TABLE")

   request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:   "cell", for: indexPath) as! customeCell

do {
        let result = try self.context.fetch(request)

        if (result.count > 0) {

            for index in 0 ..< result.count
            {
                let person = result[index] as! NSManagedObject

                if  let first = person.value(forKey : "expenseAccountCode"),
                    let last = person.value(forKey : "expenseAmount") ,
                    let second = person.value(forKey: "expenseDate")
                {

                    cell.dateText.text = String (describing: second)
                    cell.amountText.text = String (describing: last)
                    cell.nameText.text = String (describing: first)

                                       }

            }
        }
    }catch{  let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)}
    return cell
    }
```